# WCF 4.0 Schema Validation minOccurs="1" and nillable="false" (date and enummeration)

Tags: wcf, validation, date, schema

Ive just made a WCF service from a wsdl and xsd. Ive declared an element of type "date" in the xsd with minOccurs="1" and nillable="false". When not setting the variable in the service, .Net put in the default value "01-01-0001" (using soapui to see response) i.e. I do not get a SoapFault in the client. I experience this for the type "date" and "enummeration". Im using Visual Studio 2010 (I have not installed SP1, yet) and .Net 4.0 Framework. Is this a bug? PS Im using the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047%28v=vs.100%29.aspx example .Net 4.0 - the validation seems to work besides the above.

Thanks.
Nikolaj

Comment: 01-01-0001 is not the same thing as null, so I wouldn't expect a SoapFault for that value.

Comment: Hi Tim, agree, but why is it returned in the response even if I do _not_ set the variable with a value in the code?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I can't say for certain.  But DateTime does not have a null value if it's not initialized - it has a default value of 01/01/0001. If you post the relevant part of your code something else may become apparent.

Comment: Hi Tim, there is no code :-) I do _not_ have someCompositeObjectInAResponse.date = new Date(); - maybe I could use svcutil (in a way) so that the date attribute is set to null by default (which would be better than having a regexp in the xsd saying that the date must not equal 01-01-0001). I would like to get a nil element back, because of the (almost) same problem with "enummeration" - here the first declared string is returned, if I do not set (define) the variable in the response code i.e. its a valid value i.e. I do not know if the att was set actually by the developer or by .Net. Thanks.